# Can't get values from Sqlite DB using query

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I used sqlite to populate a DB with some Tables in it. 
I made a function at another javascript page that executes the database & selects some values from the table. The function is called at  $(document).ready().

Javascript:

```
 //DB Population
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "SqliteTrial", 20000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Subjects');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Subjects (id unique, subjectname)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Subjects (id, subjectname) VALUES (1, "Math")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Subjects (id, subjectname) VALUES (2, "Science")');
}  

function GetSubjectsFromDB()
{
    console.log("");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Subjects', [], queryNSuccess, errorCB);
}

function queryNSuccess(tx, results) {
    alert("Query Success");
    console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
    if (!results.rowsAffected) {
        console.log('No rows affected!');
        return false;
    }
    console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}
```

Is there some problem with this line?

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Subjects', [], queryNSuccess, errorCB);
```

The queryNSuccess isn't called, neither is the errorCB so I don't know what's wrong.

This is how I call it at another page:

Javascript:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            DisplayData();
            GetSubjectsFromDB(tx);
        });
```

Comment: How is "tx" initialized? Are there any errors reported in the console?

Comment: I put the code for tx. No errors are found in the console.

Comment: I don't see code where "tx" is set.

Comment: If your site ever goes live then your database is wide open to attack...

Comment: Your example shows how you create and populate your db - but not how you execute the statement you consider faulty (`GetSubjectsFromDB`). Please show this code instead.

Comment: @LeeTaylor There's no 'your' database here: it's a client-side storage.

Comment: @raina77ow I don't understand which code should I show

Comment: I guess I'm missing something then ... do you have any tutorials that might explain what you are saying ?

Comment: Could you just show the line in which GetSubjectsFromDB is _called_?

Comment: 'tx' is not defined in that function call.  That is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. `tx` variable is actually a parameter that will be sent into the specified callback function by `db.transaction` method. So you're probably want to do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    db.transaction(GetSubjectsFromDB);            
});
```

... and rewrite this function definition as...

```
function GetSubjectsFromDB(tx) { ... something to do with tx ... }
```

But there's another problem actually, as I see it. Your `db` variable, which stores the connection handle (created by `window.openDatabase` call) is local to `onDeviceReady` function - in other words, it's not visible outside of this function.

The easiest way to solve this is to define this variable at the Global context:

```
var dbh; // the SQLite connection handle
function onDeviceReady() { ... dbh = window.openDatabase ... }
function GetSubjects() { ... dbh.transaction(getSubjectsFromDb) ... }
function getSubjectsFromDb(tx) { ... tx.executeSql(...) ... }
```

Here's a great [presentation](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html#slide1) describing general usage of WebSQL DB. But I'd also like to add that WebSQL DB API is considered deprecated; it's recommended to use IndexedDB instead. Here's [something](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/websql-indexeddb/) to read about it.

Comment: Thanks a million @raina77ow ... Your Answer is really useful.